# I can't test when i have a JsonReader

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

With xUnit Im trying to test this function

```
public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
```

Im trying to extract the item "type" from a json like this

```
var item = JObject.Load(reader);

if (item is null)
    return null;

var itemType = item["type"]?.Value<string>();
```

And it will switch depends on the type extracted like this

```
return itemType switch
{
    nameof(One) => item.ToObject<One>(),
    nameof(Two) => item.ToObject<Two>(),
    _ => null,
};
```

I'm trying to verify this

```
public void ReadJsonVerifyTypeReturned()
{ 
    // Arrange 
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer(); 
    var converter = new CustomGetWorkOrderConverter(); 
    
    var json = @"[{ 'code': '001', 'type': 'One' }]";
    var reader = new JsonReader();             
    
    //Act
    var result = converter.ReadJson(reader, typeof (object), null, serializer);
    
    //Assert
    Assert.IsType<One>(result);
}
```

But I can't instance an abstract class like JsonReader, and I don't know hot to solve that.

Comment: FWIW, your `json` string does not actually contain valid JSON: JSON forbids the use of single-quotes, you need to use only `"` doubler-quotes for keys and values.

Comment: Use a JsonTextReader or as this is for tests create your own mock of JsonReader for tests so you can easier test "failing" behavior.

Comment: Is the ReadJson method yours? If so, how did you create JsonReader to pass into that method?